# How do I match Prometheus metric label values against Grafana variables with added characters and padding?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to match label values in a prometheus metric against a variable in a grafana dashboard.

Sample prometheus metric..

```
my_metric{short_addr="CA-1"} 20
my_metric{short_addr="NY-2500"} 50
my_metric{short_addr="NJ-25"} 15
```

Sample grafana variable would return values (long_addr) like

```
CA-loc-0001-01
NY-loc-2500-02
NJ-loc-0025-00
```

long_addr has additional 3 characters "loc", the number after it is padded to 4 digits with leading 0s, has a 2 digit suffix at the end.

When I select "CA-loc-0001-01" in the grafana variable, i want to be able to filter in all series that match "CA-1"

I can figure out how to match these two formats logically, see https://regex101.com/r/aB5A1D/1), but cant figure out how to make it work in prometheus + grafana.

I am using Grafana version 7.5

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. You need to create regex selector based on value of your variable, but there is no obvious way for it. Consider either changing your variable, or creating another variable based on value of the current one.